# Ошибка "Target class does not exist" в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Создал контроллер через консоль с помощью artisan, все создалось удачно. Однако, когда я привязал этот контролер к роуту, то возникает ошибка **Target class [PageController] does not exist.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**web.php:**

```
Route::get('/', [PageController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
```

**PageController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller {

    public function home() {
        return view('home');
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы не указали пространство имён в web.php

Попробуйте добавить

```
use App\Http\Controllers;
```

после открытия php тега

Если вы не хотите подключать простронсво имён, можно использовать использовать другой синтаксис:

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@home'])->name('home');
```

Comment: Laravel 8. У меня заработало, когда добавил в фаил web.php    "`use App\Http\Controllers\Имя_используемого_контроллера;`" 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант если используется Laravel 8

```
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
```

или

```
    Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\PageController@home')->name('home');
```

По умолчанию в Laravel 8 не подключается пространство имен `App\Http\Controllers`, поэтому следующее **работать не будет**

```
    Route::get('/', 'PageController@home')->name('home');
```

Подключить пространство имен для контроллеров можно определив в `app\Provierds\RouteServiceProvider.php` свойство

```
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```